# The argument type 'FutureBuilder<Type>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

Tags: flutter, dart

I Created CircularPercentIndicator Inside my code and I
Stored The Percent value in ShardPreference and I use FutureBuilder to Fetch The percent value from SharedPreference Like the Below code but I get The Error The argument type 'FutureBuilder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'

```
 CircularPercentIndicator(
                       radius: 30.0,
                       lineWidth: 10,
                       progressColor: Colors.white,
                       backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        
       percent: FutureBuilder(
           future: getPercentValue("index1"),
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                     return snapshot.data;} else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator(); }
                               }),),
```

//here is my Method to Fetch the Percent Value from SharedPreference

```
Future<double> getPercentValue(String key)async{
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 
 double storedvalue=  await sharedPreferences.getDouble(key)??0.0;
 return storedvalue;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swap the CircularPercentIndicator and the FutureBuilder. the `percent` parameter needs a double but you provide the FutureBuilder. So do it like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: getPercentValue("index1"),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
        return CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: 30.0,
            lineWidth: 10,
            progressColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            percent: snapshot.data);
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    }),
```

Comment: Thank You Brother You Save My day. I Works Perfectly!!